# trying to read from stdout with NONBLOCKING set using winARM newlib lpc

Tags: stdout, blocking, nonblocking, ioctl, fcntl

I want read on stdout to be non-blocking. I was using the newlib-lpc library in WINarm to do this. But even though it is set as non-Blocking, the code stops at read every time and waits for a character to be received.

Here is my read line:

```
read(fileno(stdout), &inchar, 1);
```

Here is the code to set stdout to non-blocking using newlib-lpc

```
blocking=BLOCKING_IO_NO;
ioctl( fileno(stdout), BLOCKING_SETUP, &blocking);
```

When that didn't work, I decided to forget using the library and do it myself with this line

```
fcntl(fileno(stdout), F_SETFL,fcntl(fileno(stdout), F_GETFL) |O_NONBLOCK);
```

But that didn't work either.

Could anyone give me some advice?

Thanks!

edit: 
Someone asked if I really meant stdout. Yes, I am resurrecting some old code, and the stdout has been set as the socket for UART communication between my board and the computer.

```
sp.baud   = 115200uL;
sp.length = UART_WORD_LEN_8;
sp.parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
sp.stop   = UART_STOP_BITS_1;
ioctl( fileno(stdout), UART_SETUP, &sp);

irq.FIQ = 0;
irq.pri = (INT_PRIORITY)10;
ioctl( fileno(stdout), INTERRUPT_SETUP, &irq);
```

edit2: They used stdout this way so that printf works. When it tries to print to stdout, it gets redirected to the UART serial stream.

edit3: The error I get when calling

```
 ioctl( fileno(stdout), BLOCKING_SETUP, &blocking);
```

is

```
errno88 function not implemented
```

Comment: Read from `stdout`?  Didn't you mean `stdin`?

Comment: No, I am resurrecting some old code and in this, they read from stdout...

Comment: I just posted some code that explains why stdout a bit better